# assymetric graph coloring formulation

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I'm reading this [articel](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.10191) which is about formulating VCP to eleminate symmetric solution, they say:

[image]

And then In order to eliminate some of the symmetrical solutions, they say these two constraint is enough :

[image]

My question is: Why do we need to have equation 5. I've tried to compare different symmetric coloring and it seems that only having equation 6 is enough to ensure asymtric solution. Right?
So, why we have to have 5 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraint $(5)$ enforces the logical implication $w_i = 1 \implies \bigvee_{v\in V} (x_{vi} = 1)$.  Without it, you could have $w_i=1$ but $x_{vi}=0$ for all $v$, which means that you didn't really use color $i$.  At optimality, this would not happen because you could improve the objective by permuting the colors, but imposing $(5)$ ensures that every feasible solution uses only consecutive colors starting from $1$.

Comment: Hi @RobPratt thaks. Do you mean without 5 the problem formulation is not compeletly correct? I think to formulate coloring only 1-4 are enough. and 5 and 6 are there to only improve the formulation. But once you wrote we could have $w_i =1$ and at the same time $x_{vi} =0 \forall v$ , this seems that 5 is neccessary. Right?

Comment: Especially when the objective function is $ min \sum w_i$

Comment: Yes, 1-4 are enough for correctness.  And to eliminate symmetry, 5 is necessary only if you stop early, before finding an optimal solution.